# CSS how to break flow in just one direction

Tags: css

**Motivation**
CSS does not allow styling the options of an html select component, so I'm building a custom "component" to do so.

**The challenge is this**
Along the x-direction it needs to keep the inline flow.
Along the y-direction, it needs to be able to overlap content below it.

**Here's an example** (does not break flow)
http://jsfiddle.net/4tyvLmqn/1

html

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="item selected">asdflkhj asdf adf</div>
  <div class="item">b</div>
  <div class="item">c</div>
  <div class="item">ad fds adfs dfsa fsd fasd</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
<hr />
This should not move down
<hr />
```

JS (click handler - there may be a pure CSS way to do this)

```js
document.querySelector('.dropdown .selected').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('isOpen')
})
```

SCSS

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.item {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;

  &.selected {
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
  }

  .isOpen & {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen - if your issue is with CSS and not Sass, please include your compiled CSS, instead. Otherwise, if your question is about how to do something in Sass that you can already do in CSS, please clarify that and add the Sass tag.

Comment: keep a fixed height then simply adjust overflow (visible/hidden)

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the suggestion! I can mark your answer as correct if you add it below. Here's what I have so far. What's needed now is to scroll to the correct item in the list, but that's another problem to solve

http://jsfiddle.net/n4zm3xue/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep a fixed height then adjust overflow (visible/hidden). You can also consider a `max-height` in case you will have a lot of elements.

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', e => {
  dropdown.classList.toggle('isOpen')
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: calc(1em + 2 * 0.5em);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.isOpen {
  overflow: visible;
}

.background {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  border: inherit;
  margin: -1px;
  max-height: calc(5*(1em + 2 * 0.5em));
}
.isOpen .background {
  overflow:auto;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="item">Select an Item</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">ad fds adfs dfsa fsd fasd</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
    <div class="item">ad fds adfs dfsa fsd fasd</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
    <div class="item">ad fds adfs dfsa fsd fasd</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr /> This should not move down
<hr />
```

Answer (score 1):

Snippet here seems not to be working with CSS3. I have created a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/42mpa6wn/

**Javascript:**

```
document.querySelector('.dropdown .selected').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('isOpen')
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  height:25px;
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}

.isOpen .itemlist{
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width:inherit;
  top:calc(100% - 20px);
}

.item {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;

  &.selected {
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
  }

  .isOpen & {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<hr />
This should not move
<hr />
This should not move
<hr />
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="itemlist">
    <div class="item selected">asdflkhj asdf adf</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">ad fds adfs dfsa fsd fasd</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
This should not move down
<hr />
```

Basically, you want `.dropdown` to be `relative` to the page, where we put it. also, you want `.itemlist` to be in `absolute` position when the dropdown action is triggered. You still need to beautify it